# 256-colour terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I've been battling it out with this 256-colour terminal malarkey and I just can't get decent colour displays in a terminal. I'm using ubuntu-server with `openssh` and `zsh`. I have tried accessing the machine from both Windows (Putty) and RHEL (`gnome-terminal`) and neither of them displays the colours properly.

I double checked that:

- $TERM is set to `xterm-256color`
- There is a file present in `/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`

Whenever I use a vim or oh-my-zsh theme, the colours are all ANSI based. What am I missing?

EDIT:
Oh I should also say that when i do

```
echo "$FG[214]Blah"
```

Then it displays using 256 colours. Neither the prompt nor vim displays the colours I expect.

Comment: Which terminal are you using on RHEL? zsh is only a shell, it doesn't have anything to do with colours.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to be more accurate

Comment: Besides setting `TERM` to `xterm-256color` various programs may require additional configuration to tell them to take advantage of the extended color palette. What terminfo file does the `infocmp` command say you’re using?

Comment: infocmp says 'colors#8'...

Comment: Was this ever figured out?

Comment: Do putty and gnome-terminal have 256-colour-capability? If yes, do they expect xterm-256color control codes or their own ones? In the latter case, using `export TERM=xterm-256color` won't help you utilizing 256 colour support and you need to find a terminfo file that corresponds to your actually used terminal (putty or gnome-terminal, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `COLORTERM` on the server.

In my case (ubuntu gnome-terminal to ubuntu server), adding this to ~/.bashrc solved it:

`export COLORTERM=gnome-terminal`